# coo_matrix TypeError: data type not understood

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pytorch

**Steps**

```
import torch
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

row = torch.ones([10000], dtype=torch.float32)
col = torch.ones([10000], dtype=torch.float32)
data = torch.ones([10000], dtype=torch.float32)
fn = 5120
bm = 10000

coo_matrix((data, (row, col)), shape=(fn, bm))
```

**Error Produced**

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in  
File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/sparse/coo.py", line 161, in **init**
self.data = np.array(obj, copy=copy, dtype=data_dtype)
TypeError: data type not understood

**Versions**
Python 3.8.8
numpy  1.17.5
torch  1.7.1

Comment: `coo_matrix` is a `scipy` class operating on numpy arrays, you are feeding it with `torch.tensors` - what are you expecting? You should use [`torch.sparse`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html) instead of scipy's sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this problem:-

1. Use a tensor based function that accepts the tensors as default (Use [torch.sparse_coo_tensor](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html))
2. Convert the tensors to numpy arrays using

> tensor_data.cpu().detach().numpy()